# grouping a variable in boolean indexing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new with pandas and i am bit confused with boolean indexing in pandas dataframes. So the line of code is this.

```
df['good_1994'] = (df['year'] == '1994') & (df['fizzy_drinks_sales'] > average_1994)
```

I want to isolate the df['fizzy_drinks_sales'] for only 1994 year. How is the right way to write it 
in boolean indexing like this one?

Comment: try: `df["good_1994"] = ((df['year'] == '1994') & (df['fizzy_drinks_sales'] > average_1994)).astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this:

```
df['good_1994'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x['year] == '1994]) & (x['fizzy_drinks_sales'] > average_1994), axis=1)
```

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To filter the dataframe to return only where `fizzy_drinks_sales` occurred in 1994, the code is:

```
df[df['fizzy_drinks_sales'] == '1994']
```

Check out [10 Minutes to Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/10min.html), the new documentation for 1.0. It will help you learn to navigate the basics quickly.